# Syntax error on selenium xpath expression

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath

I'm building a selenium `findElement by.xpath` expression, very complex, and it appears there is a syntax error.

I don't really know XML language so I made mistake(s) obviously, could someone tell where are the mistake(s) ? :)

Thanks!

I have a list of projects on a web page, in each project there are sub-projects, I want a specific one, I know the `name` and the `subName`.

The html code is something like :

```
<table id="list_proj" class="table tablebas table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tbody style="height:1em;overflow-y:scroll"></tbody>
  <tbody style="height:1em;overflow-y:scroll"></tbody>
  <tbody style="height:1em;overflow-y:scroll">
    <tr class="caption">
      <td class="app_name" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;" colspan="11">
        <b>
          <a href="?page=applications&mode=edit&app_id=3" style="padding-left:10px;" data-icon="">  Application SEVo</a>
        </b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data"></tr>
    <tr class="data"></tr>
    <tr class="data">
      <td title="Pas de commentaire !" style="text-align:left">
        <img alt="MCO" src="/colibri/images/corner-dots.gif"></img>
        <a href="?page=projects&mode=view&project_id=9" style="padding-left:5px">MCO</a>
      </td>
      <td>0.50</td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2">
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
  </tbody>
  <tbody style="height:1em;overflow-y:scroll"></tbody>
</table>
```

And my xpath expression :

```
driver.findElement(
By.xpath(
"((//a[contains(text(),'"+name+"')])[1]
.(ancestor::td[@class='caption'])[1]
.following-sibling::td[@class='data']
.descendant::(a[contains(text(),'"+subName+"')])[1])[1]"
));
```

Sorry for the mess ^^'

Comment: What exactly you want to identify here?

Comment: I want to click on the link subName

Comment: you can directly identify subName, is it necessary to identify using `name`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes because some other projects has the same sub-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below `xPath` which is more better :-

```
//a[contains(.,'"+name+"')]/ancestor::tr/following::a[contains(.,'"+subName+"')]

for eg. :- //a[contains(.,'Application SEVo')]/ancestor::tr/following::a[contains(.,'MCO')]
```

**Updated..**

another one is :-

```
//a[contains(.,'"+name+"')]/following::a[contains(.,'"+subName+"')]
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Thanks :) it's shorter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know xPath with selenium, but I think the syntax error should be in the line below

```
.descendant::(a[contains(text(),'"+subName+"')])[1])[1]
```

Should be

```
.descendant::(//a[contains(text(),'"+subName+"')])[1])[1]
```

? (note the "//a")

Comment: It still is invalid :/

Comment: why in line
    ".(ancestor::td[@class='caption'])[1]"
the ancestor is within "()" ? is it correct?

Comment: please, use the following xPath formula: 
`(//a[contains(text(),'"+name+"')][1]/ancestor::tr[@class='caption'][1]/following-sibling::td[@class='data']/descendant::a[contains(text(),'subName')][1])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
//a[contains(text(),'"+name+"')]/ancestor::tr[@class='caption']/following-sibling::tr[@class='data']//a[contains(text(),'"+subName+"')]
```

Don't use `index` `[1]` everytime, If you are sure that only one element would be returned, there is no point of putting index in every descendant or ancestor call.

Comment: It doesn't return any match

Comment: can you post the correct `HTML` ... I can see error here `<tr class="data">..</tr>
    <a>subName</a>
  </tr>`  ... which is the `tr` where `a` is present. I dn't see any starting `tr`

Answer (score 0):

```
"((//a[contains(text(),'"+name+"')])[1]
.(ancestor::td[@class='caption'])[1]
.following-sibling::td[@class='data']
.descendant::(a[contains(text(),'"+subName+"')])[1])[1]"
```

There's so much wrong with this it's hard to know where to start. First, we don't know what's in the variables name and subName - if these strings contain single quotes then anything might happen (injection attack). Secondly, it seems to be using "." as a separator between steps in the path when it should use "/". Third, what follows an axis like "descendant::" must be a NodeTest, and that rules out a parenthesized expression.

I think there's a real problem in your approach. Writing a complex expression in a language you don't understand and then asking on SO what the syntax errors mean is not going to be a good way to make progress. (Once you've got rid of the syntax errors, will you then know what the XPath actually means?). Do some reading and learn the language properly; don't try to drive a car without taking driving lessons.